# Renderizar HTML usando PHP

Tags: php, html

Este questionamento é muito grande e passível de múltiplas respostas porem não obtive respostas em fórum de discussões.
Bem gostaria de saber como construir a seguinte pagina utilizando PHP (mas construi utilizando html):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ela possui o seguinte código HTML:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Titulo</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Jquery-Validate/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Javascript/ActionsJS.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../datepicker/css/datepicker.css" media="screen" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/StyleSheet.css"/>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"><!--------- START Navbar --------->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header"><!-- START Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> 
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button> 
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Meu Site</a>
            </div><!-- END Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"><!-- START Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login_modal">Login</button></li>
                    <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#create_account_modal">Create Account</button></li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form span7 text-center" role="search" id="search-form" action="../action.php" method="get">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" id="search_input" name="search_input" placeholder="Search" />
                        <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="search_form_submit" value="search">Search</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div><!-- END Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        </div>
    </nav><!--------- END Navbar --------->

    <div class="wrapper" role="main"><!-- START Content -->
        <div class="container"><!-- START Related Tags -->
            <div class="row">
                <div id="right_sidebar" class="col-md-2 pull-right"><!-- START Right Sidebar -->
                    <div class="row">
                        <h4>Duraçao</h4>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label><input type="radio" name="duratrion" value="dur-0" checked="checked">Indeterminado</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label><input type="radio" name="duratrion" value="dur-1">1 Dia</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label><input type="radio" name="duratrion" value="dur-2">3 Dias</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label><input type="radio" name="duratrion" value="dur-3">5 Dias</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

para que eu possa intercambiar este pequenos elementos entre outras 
páginas (.php) veja meu exemplo rudimentar:
Criei este arquivo header.php (que renderiza o navbar em vermelho)

```
<?php
echo'
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Titulo</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Jquery-Validate/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Javascript/ActionsJS.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" media="screen" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../datepicker/css/datepicker.css" media="screen" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../CSS/StyleSheet.css"/>

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"><!--------- START Navbar --------->
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header"><!-- START Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> 
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button> 
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Meu Site</a>
                </div><!-- END Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"><!-- START Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login_modal">Login</button></li>
                        <li><button type="button" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#create_account_modal">Create Account</button></li>
                    </ul>
                    <form class="navbar-form span7 text-center" role="search" id="search-form" action="../action.php" method="get">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" id="search_input" name="search_input" placeholder="Search" />
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="search_form_submit" value="search">Search</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div><!-- END Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            </div>
        </nav><!--------- END Navbar --------->
    </body>
</html>
';
?>
```

Creio que está não é a melhor forma e gostaria de saber qual seria uma forma adequada, onde eu pude-se chamar estes pequenos .php (contendo o navbar "vermelho" o sidebar em "verde") e construir uma pagina unica
ainda tem outros pontos que seriam 1º o fato de que estou replicando a tag  nas paginas header.php e sidebar.php como eu poderia ser mais eficiente neste apecto?
2º o conteudo da tag  é diferentes entre cada pagina 
3º em caso de login do usuario como alteraria os botões Login e Create account no .php para um botão logout?

Comment: você colocou "renderizar o html com php", mas este não é o problema, por que de certa forma eles estão ligados e quem renderiza é o cliente-side, poderia explicar qual o objetivo, de preferência escreva por "tópicos" (de maneira mais organizada), obrigado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento o objetivo é quebrar o HTML (que gera a imagem) em pequenos codigos phps. para que seja possivel montar um codigo .php que importe por exemplo um cabeçalho.php sidebar.php, formulario.php e crie uma pagina unica com estas partes

Comment: você deixou isto claro no comentário, mas eu não havia entendido isto na questão, pois o titulo leva a entender outra coisa. Escrever por tópicos ajuda :) Mas entendi sim o que você necessita, na minha opinião é algo que pode realmente obter várias respostas diferentes, mas não é uma questão inválida. Quanto ao seu código **eu pessoalmente** (minha opinião apenas) acho que se for por questão de organização, você deveria pensar seriamente em um sistema de *Template* e talvez um *MVC*.

Comment: postei um exemplo em .php onde o cabeçalho é gerado pelo arquvio .php como eu faria para "ligar" este cabeçalho a um arquivo .php que gera o rodapé por exemplo?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A forma mais simples para fazer isso é separar o HTML em pequenos blocos e colocar eles em arquivos distintos. Isso vai simplificar a manutenção dos arquivos e evitar as repetições que você comentou. No final é só unir os pedaços em um outro arquivo PHP.

Uma das formas para você juntar estes pedaços é usando [`include`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.include.php). Este permite que você inclua o conteúdo de outros arquivos no arquivo que você está chamando.

Segue um exemplo funcional:

index.php

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <div class="cabecalho">
      <?php include 'cabecalho.php'; ?>
    </div>
    <div class="barra_lateral">
      <?php include 'barra_lateral.php'; ?>
    </div>
    <h1>Página inicial</h1>
    <p>Esta é a primeira página.</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

cabecalho.php

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/index.php">Página inicial</a></li>
  <li><a href="/contato.php">Contato</a></li>
</ul>
```

barra_lateral.php

```
<ol>
  <li>Este é o primeiro item</li>
  <li>Este é o segundo item</li>
</ol>
```

Uma forma mais elegante é usar uma [linguagem de template](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_template). As linguagens de templates permitem que você crie uma saída baseado em um modelo - um arquivo HTML cheio de "lacunas" para serem preenchidas - que você pode adicionar lógica para controlar o que será exibido.

Se quiser seguir por este caminho eu indico que você olhe o [Smarty](http://www.smarty.net/) e o [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/).

E como foi comentado pelo @GuilhermeNascimento e @WallaceMaxters, uma ótima maneira de resolver este e vários outros problemas que você vai enfrentar é usando MVC, alguns frameworks bem conhecidos implementam este padrão como o [Zend](http://www.zend.org/), o [CodeIgniter](http://www.codeigniter.com/) e o [CakePHP](http://cakephp.org/).

Comment: mas nesta solução é dinamica? pois haverá um cadastro e login de usuarios e existem areas onde o só será permitida a visualização de membros

Comment: Um MVC também cairia bem :)

Comment: @WallaceMaxters huahuahua foi o mesmo que comentei na questão, um *MVC* + *template*, seria o melhor caminho :) +1 ae pra ti

Comment: @RicardoHenrique a parte dinâmica terá que ser feita dentro de cada arquivo verificando se o usuário está logado ou não. Pela sua pergunta eu tinha entendido apenas que você queria saber como seria possível organizar os arquivos.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, editei minha resposta para incluir o MVC, obrigado pelo comentário.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, editei minha resposta para incluir o MVC, obrigado pelo comentário

Comment: Só uma dica, parenteses em `include()` não é necessário, prefira `include '...';`

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, ótima dica. Tem uma explicação legal aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21572779/845307 - TL;DR: O `include` não é uma função por isso não há a necessidade de parênteses.

Comment: Exatamente @JonatasOliveira

Answer (score 2):

@Ricardo, conforme respondeu o nosso amigo @Jonatas Oliveira, e respondendo a sua pergunta no comentário, a solução colocada é **estática**. Veja as diferenças entre:

include()
require()
include_once()
require_once()

```
ANTES DE TUDO SOBRE SUA PERGUNTA PRINCIPAL:
```

- Você PODE criar condições dentro de um arquivo.php que escondam, dinamicamente, os seus códigos html. Um exemplo bem básico, sem precisar criar includes, seria isto:

```
    global $user;
    $user = $_SESSION['estouLogado'];
    if(isset($user) ){

echo '<div style="text-align: right;"><h4>Bem vindo, '.$user->get_user_name()."</h4>";
echo '</div>';
       }else{ ?>

        <!-- BOTÃO ENTRAR EM HTML--> 

    <?php } ?>
```

**AGORA SOBRE AS FUNÇÕES:**

**include();**

A função include() do PHP tem como objetivo incluir (como sugere o nome) um arquivo dentro do outro quando acessado. Caso ocorra algum problema na inclusão deste, será apresentado um Warning (aviso) que não foi possível incluir o arquivo e continuará a exibição da página normalmente sem a inclusão do arquivo. A função include() aceita parâmetros via GET quando chama um arquivo. Confira o exemplo abaixo.

```
<?php
  //Exemplo de utilização da função include()
  include('./arquivo1.php?perfil=123'); //incluindo o arquivo1.php
  include('./lembrete.html'); //incluindo o arquivo lembrete.html
?>
```

No exemplo acima, estão sendo incluídos 2 arquivos: arquivo1.php e lembrete.html. Estes arquivos serão incluídos sem problema algum desde que eles estejam no mesmo caminho que foi informado como parâmetro no uso da função include();

---

**require();**

A função require() do PHP tem a mesma funcionalidade da função include(), citada acima, com a diferença que se caso o arquivo que você está incluindo não exista (ou não seja encontrado), será gerado um Fatal Error (erro fatal), paralizando a execução de qualquer script que venha após a linha do require(); outra divergência é o fato desta função não aceitar parâmetros via GET para o arquivo chamado. Caso você utilize este parâmetro, ele será ignorado. Confira o exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php
  //Exemplo de utilização da função require()
  require('./arquivo1.php'); //incluindo o arquivo1.php
  require('./lembrete.html'); //incluindo o arquivo lembrete.html
?>
```

---

**include_once(); e require_once();**

As funções include_once() e require_once() do PHP tem as suas funcionalidades “idênticas” às funções include() e require(), respectivamente. Digo “idênticas” (entre aspas) pois a única diferença entre elas é o fato da funções que possuem o “_once” só permitirem a inclusão do arquivo uma única vez na página.

```
<?php
  //Exemplo de utilização da função include() e include_once()
  include('./arquivo1.php'); //incluindo o arquivo1.php
  include('./lembrete.html'); //incluindo o arquivo lembrete.html
  include_once('./arquivo1.php'); //tentando incluir o arquivo1.php novamente, ele não será incluso (caso o arquivo não exista, será apresentado um segundo warning)
?>

<?php
  //Exemplo de utilização da função require() e require_once()
  require('./arquivo1.php'); //incluindo o arquivo1.php
  require('./lembrete.html'); //incluindo o arquivo lembrete.html
  require_once('./arquivo1.php'); //tentando incluir o arquivo1.php novamente, ele não será incluso
?>
```

Comment: ,@Rafael gostaria de dividir a mesma pagina(a da imagem) em componentes, 3 componentes (o cabeçalho em vermelho, os botoes em verde e a lateral em azul) cada componente em um arquivo .php e gostaria de montar os 3 componentes atraves de um Quarto arquivo .php,  como poderia fazer isso? de modo que eu pude-se ficar reaproveitando estes componentes, porem tem algumas restrições o conteudo do <head> varia de pagina para pagina. lembrando que não deverá(assim como css dentro de html) ter codigo .php dentro de código .html

Comment: @RicardoHenrique, HTML é uma linguagem de marcação. Ela não uma linguagem na qual você pode criar lógicas e determinar ações, aliás, ela NEM É UMA LINGUAGEM DE PROGRAMAÇÃO. Eu não entendo qual a sua dificuldade em fazer includes. Acho que você deve estudar mais PHP. Um dia você conseguirá. Abraço.